# Wrap a Span Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have toggle menu. The code is working fine, the problem is the first time there is a span inside the  but when I click on the menu the span is missing. I'm using this span to show the down arrow. I need to wrap a span inside  as shown as the below code on every click. Here is my code

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 seach-blk">
            <a href="#" class="srch-btnnew" id="open-menu">@selectedProductType <span></span></a>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
                    <ul>

    <li><a href='#'><span class="product-type">categoryName 1</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class="product-type">categoryName 2</span></a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // Initially hide submenu
     $('#cssmenu').hide();
     $('#open-menu').click(function (e) {
         //Prevent href
         e.preventDefault();
         // Toggle the menu item
         $('#cssmenu').toggle();
     });

 });
```

CSS

```
.srch-btnnew span {
position: absolute;
right: 15px;
background: url(../images/down-arrownew.png) repeat-x;
width: 12px;
height: 9px;
top: 22px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Working fine for me, check http://jsfiddle.net/5mspQ/ Check if any other js is not modifying it. In fiddle just inspect the element it will show span

Comment: I really couldn't understand what you want to do?

Comment: Nothing in code shown would change the html. Has to be from other code. QUestion is not very understandable

Comment: are you facing problem when you click on link then the span is disappear

Comment: at first time the span is there when click on the li the span is disappear

Comment: when you say  not there...is it gone from live html viewed in browser console? Or you just can't see it? There's a big difference

Comment: @charlietfl it gone from live html

Comment: without seeing more code won't get much help...hide/show code won't remove it

Comment: Do you have any live demo?

Answer (score 1):

You are using empty html `<span></span>` that's why the browser might be removing that. So try using `<span>&nbsp;</span>`

Or you could put some text in span and use `font-size: 0;` for that.

Also try `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: browsers don't typically remove empty elements

Comment: @Arun Sorry! There might be another problem...]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Not span removed when clicking a tag.

I have tested in jsfiddle find the below link

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/BgLQP/)

I m not sure ,maybe in your a tag  need space like ('&nbsp') otherwise CSS is affecting your arrow path

**CODE :**

```
// Initially hide submenu
     $('#cssmenu').hide();
     $('#open-menu').click(function (e) {
         //Prevent href
         e.preventDefault();
         // Toggle the menu item
         $('#cssmenu').toggle();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` element is not being removed. It is an inline element, and therefore width and height do not apply to it. You can change it to a block element by adding `display: inline-block;` to the styling.

```
.srch-btnnew span {
    display: inline-block;  /* <-- Add this to make it a block element */
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    background: url(../images/down-arrownew.png) repeat-x;
    width: 12px;
    height: 9px;
    top: 22px;
}
```